# PHP image Resize and Crop Function

Tags: php, cakephp, image-processing, crop

I want a function which when i upload a photo it should crop the image irrespective of the ration of the image from the centre making sure the crop is well inside the image.

[image]

the above image is 2592 * 1944

i want to crop an image of 159 * 129

[image]

and this is what i get when using a plugin for cakephp (Miles Johnsons Upload Plugin)

can some one help me find a image crop function to do this or help me with the algorithm in doing the same.

Comment: Did you mean 'resize' instead of 'crop'?

Comment: resize, crop, or resize AND crop?

Comment: i am not sure how to do it the right way. i want the final image to be of the largest part of the image but of the size i need. so i think it may be resize and crop or other combinations. am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is solved, checkout the latest version of cake-uploader pluign.
https://github.com/milesj/cake-uploader/commit/2be63f32730755cffbace17ee8fa2d686785964d

Answer (score 1):

I've used this: http://shiftingpixel.com/2008/03/03/smart-image-resizer/ to create all the image thumbnails found here: http://www.patriciashin.com/painting.php

Comment: Sorry I didn't add more, my laptop battery died. Anyway, this script is extremely customizable. Their documentation is pretty good. I think I was even able to tweak the script to better meet my needs. Cakephp makes it fairly easy to into 3rd party scripts, but you might have to concert this script to a class to be most effective. Let me know your thoughts and I'd be willing to help out.

Comment: looks promising. I am planning to build a plugin are release it as open source. would you be interested ? since the scripts out there i didnt find a lot of them doing proper resize and cropping.

Comment: Sure I'd be interested. Just contact me offsite to coordinate. I don't always have tons of time, but I'll help however I can.

Answer (score 1):

I must say i have not thoroughly tested this piece of code, I modified it for personal use and this should help out your problem.

Replace the function crop in plugin/uploader/vendor/uploader.php

near line 368

with the following function

```
 public function crop(array $options = array(), $explicit = false) {
    if ($this->_data[$this->_current]['group'] != 'image' || !$this->_enabled) {
        return false;
    }

    $options = $options + array('location' => self::LOC_CENTER, 'quality' => 100, 'width' => null, 'height' => null, 'append' => null, 'prepend' => null);
    $width = $this->_data[$this->_current]['width'];
    $height = $this->_data[$this->_current]['height'];
    $src_x = 0;
    $src_y = 0;
    $dest_w = $width;
    $dest_h = $height;
    $location = $options['location'];

    if (is_numeric($options['width']) && is_numeric($options['height'])) {
        $newWidth = $options['width'];
        $newHeight = $options['height'];

        if ($width / $newWidth > $height / $newHeight) {
            $dest_h = $options['height'];
            $dest_w = round($width / ($height / $newHeight));
        } else {
            $dest_w = $options['width'];
            $dest_h = round($height / ($width / $newWidth));
        }
    } else {
        if ($width > $height) {
            $newWidth = $height;
            $newHeight = $height;
        } else {
            $newWidth = $width;
            $newHeight = $width;
        }

        $dest_h = $newHeight;
        $dest_w = $newWidth;
    }

    $src_x = 0;
    $src_y = 0;
    if ($dest_w > $newWidth) {
            $src_x = ceil(( ($dest_w - $newWidth) / 2) * ($height / $newHeight));
    }

    if ($dest_h > $newHeight) {
            $src_y = ceil(( ($dest_h - $newHeight) / 2) * ($width / $newWidth));
    }

    $append = '_cropped_' . $newWidth . 'x' . $newHeight;

    if ($options['append'] !== false && empty($options['append'])) {
        $options['append'] = $append;
    }

    $transform = array(
        'width' => $newWidth,
        'height' => $newHeight,
        'source_x' => $src_x,
        'source_y' => $src_y,
        'source_w' => $width,
        'source_h' => $height,
        'dest_w' => $dest_w,
        'dest_h' => $dest_h,
        'target' => $this->setDestination($this->_data[$this->_current]['name'], true, $options, false),
        'quality' => $options['quality']
    );
    if ($this->transform($transform)) {

        return $this->_returnData($transform, $append, $explicit);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Kind Regards.